# Why won't the function to roll dice also execute the statement to check for the winner in my Pig Game?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, game-development

I am trying to code the dice rolling game "Pig Game". The aim of the game is to role the dice repeatedly and the cumulative value of each dice roll is added to each player's current score. If the player holds the final value of the current score will be added to their total score. The first player to reach a score of 10 (10 for test purposes, 100 in final game) will win. If the dice gives a value of 1, the player loses their current score for that turn (but not their total score overall).
I have 4 main functions. One of them is to roll the dice. This function is executed using an event listener.it also updates the current score every time the dice is rolled and if 1 is rolled, it switches the players. I currently have an if statement that will check for a winner within the function for the hold button, but I would prefer it in the roll dice button so you roll a value that exceeds 10, you win and don't have to press hold.

The issue is with the second if statement denoted by an arrow. none of the lines of code work. I have tried having it as an else if to the if above (diceValue!==1). I have tried having it execute outside the function. I cannot work out why it doesn't work. Originally it was within my holdBtn function and worked. But doesn't work within my rollBtn function where I actually want it to work.

```js
'use strict';

const score0El = document.getElementById('score--0');
const score1El = document.getElementById('score--1');
const diceEl = document.querySelector('.dice');
const btnNew = document.querySelector('.btn--new');
const btnHold = document.querySelector('.btn--hold');
const btnRoll = document.querySelector('.btn--roll');
const player0El = document.querySelector('.player--0');
const player1El = document.querySelector('.player--1');

let scores = [0, 0];
let currentScore = 0;
let activePlayer = 0;

score0El.textContent = '0';
score1El.textContent = '0';

diceEl.classList.add('hidden');

const diceOptions = [
  'dice-1.png',
  'dice-2.png',
  'dice-3.png',
  'dice-4.png',
  'dice-5.png',
  'dice-6.png',
];

const rollBtn = function() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * diceOptions.length);

  diceEl.src = diceOptions[randomIndex];
  diceEl.classList.remove('hidden');
  const diceValue = randomIndex + 1;
  let currentPlayer = document.getElementById(`current--${activePlayer}`);

  if (diceValue !== 1) {

    currentScore += diceValue;

    currentPlayer.textContent = currentScore;
    if (scores[activePlayer] >= 10) { ** < -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- **
      console.log('You have won');

      document
        .querySelector(`.player--${activePlayer}`)
        .classList.add('player--winner');

      document
        .querySelector(`.player--${activePlayer}`)
        .classList.remove('player--active');
      diceEl.classList.add('hidden');
      btnHold.removeEventListener('click', holdBtn);
      btnRoll.removeEventListener('click', rollBtn);
    }
  } else {

    switchPlayer();
  }
};
```

Comment: I never see `scores[activePlayer]` updated ..  So it looks to me like it's always [`0,0]`  ...  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it needs `scores[activePlayer] += currentScore`

Comment: debug `console.log(diceValue, currentScore, activePlayer, scores[activePlayer], scores[activePlayer] >= 10);` You can see that you are not increasing the value you are checking...

Comment: @doublesharp yes and no, would be adding it to the index and not the current scor variable.

Comment: yes you're right I did update the scores array in the holdBtn function with scores[activePlayer] += currentScore; //player1 is index 0, 2 is index 1.  add the current score to the index.
  console.log(scores[activePlayer]);
  document.getElementById(`score--${activePlayer}`).textContent =
    scores[activePlayer];
which I tried doing here but it executes when scores[activePlayer]<10 as well. from the console it seems like it is adding the more than the dice value when calculating current score

Comment: since scores isnt updated it will never determine a winner.  What you need to do is to just put in something like `scores[activePlayer] = currentScore;`